# How to configure maven plugin from command line?

Tags: command-line, plugin, maven

I'm trying to configure JaCoCo maven plugin from command line insted of using `pom.xml`. I have managed to execute `prepare-agent` so far with command:

```
mvn -X -Djacoco.destFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
```

with output:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:prepare-agent from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:prepare-agent' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) destFile = /src/coverage/jacoco.exec
...
```

which creates `./coverage/jacoco.exec` file and now I'm trying to run `report` stage but I am not able to set properties for this stage. I'm running command:

```
mvn -X -Djacoco.dataFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec -Djacoco.outputDirectory=./jacoco_ut org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

or

```
mvn -X -DdataFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec -DoutputDirectory=./jacoco_ut org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

as in [jacoco:report](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html) there is no `user property` as in [jacoco:prepare-agent](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html).

I have output like:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:report' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) dataFile = /src/target/jacoco.exec
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /src/target/site/jacoco
[DEBUG]   (f) outputEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: project:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT @ /src/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

with default values.